# Symfony2: Customize database connection, cache and log folders, based on incoming request

Tags: php, symfony, multi-tenant

I am trying to build a multi-tenanted solution, using an existing codebase, but with segregated databases, cache and log files.

An effective way of doing this would be to dynamically compute the following, based on an incoming requests domain name:

- database connection parameters
- cache folder
- log folder

In Symfony1.x, I could do this by creating a custom filter class, but I don't know how to do this in Symfony2.

My question then is this:

How may I modify the above parameters for a symfon2 application - based on an incoming request?

Comment: $kernel = new AppKernel($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], false);

Comment: @JurgisGregov: Could you elaborate some more?. I don't see how the single line statement you suggested, helps achieve the desired functionality - please enlighten me further.

Comment: Lets say you make config_google.com.yml, config_yahoo.com.yml, etc. You get environments for each host. Passing domain as environment name in kernel construction in app.php lets you use same codebase for multiple domains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Jurgis Gregov.

You should change in your web/app.php line:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

to:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], false);
```

The first argument of AppKernel is environment **name**

After that you can create in app/config a new config files with name: 
config_**name**.yml

Where you can set doctrine configuration.

Your cache will be in folder: app/cache/**name**

And your logs will be in: app/logs/**name**.log (You can also set path to log in config yml file)

I don't know if there is other way to change doctrine parameters but i know that you can also chanage logs and cache folder by override methods:
getLogDir() and getCacheDir() in your app/AppKernel.php where you can use REQUEST to set it.